# How to open only selected database in Azure Data Studio connection

Tags: azure-data-studio

Previously in Azure Data Studio, when clicking on a saved connection the application immediately opened the database specified in the connection details. But, now (in recent update?) when clicking on one of the saved connections ADS instead open just the server - where you then have to find the right database by performing a lot of scrolling (which for me is an issue, as the server contains a large number of databases). Is it possible to configure the application so that the connection leads directly to the database (as it did before) - which would save me a lot of time.

**Is it possible to configure the Azure Data Studio Connection to again *only* open the database specified in the Connection Details?**

Comment: can you please share the details of the ADS installed on your machine (mainly Version, Commit and Date)?

Comment: I'm using the latest stable version (currently version 0.32.9)

Comment: Are you sure? The latest stable release is 1.9.0. The 0.32.9 version goes back to August 2018. Anyway, it works fine in the 1.9.0 version. If you chose a database when creating a connection,  it opens the database specified in the connection details.

Comment: Sorry, looked at the wrong computer :) (I looked at my virtual machine). My version is also 1.9.0. Strange if it works for you but not me..

Comment: I have tried adding new databases too, but they still only show the "Databases, Security, Server Objects" - folders; I still have to find the correct database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was just a bug in the application, and has been solved in 1.10.0.